# AWS - How can I add EMR step in current step

Tags: java, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster that runs a single step - custom JAR. I need to create a second step from the first step at runtime, how can I do it? I know I can do it using the CLI but how can I accomplish it using java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use AWS SDK for Java http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html

Please refer to this API reference - especially the addJobFlowSteps method
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/AmazonElasticMapReduce.html

Comment: First thanks for the quick reply. Second as i see it this class is used for creating new cluster while i want to create new step from a jar running in an existing cluster.

Comment: This class is a wrapper around their EMR Webservice interface.  I dont think this interface lets you create a new cluster.  You should however be able add a step using this interface using the addJobFlowSteps method.  The webservice api reference may be a bit more helpful - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_AddJobFlowSteps.html